# Django Crispy Forms not working as fully intended

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

currently learning how to use Django and following Corey Shafer's videos to learn. So far I am able to follow along pretty easily but I am running into a formatting error when trying to use crispy forms. Right now when using it, it works to an extent but not fully.

[Here is what I am currently getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hByr2.png)

[Here is what is expected from the videos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UYAA.png)

As you can see, some of it works as intended with proper feedback and the descriptions formatted a little more clearer. But as you can see the text isn't formatted to be smaller and the feedback text isn't red but just bolded. I included below what I added to html template to implement crispy. Also for my settings.py I made sure to add `CRSIPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'`  and included it under my INSTALLED APPS list. This is my first time posting so if there is any information I am missing please let me know, thank you for your time!

```html
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content%}
    <div class = "content-selection">
        <form method = "POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class = "form-group">
                <legend class = "border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class = "form-group">
                <button class = "btn btn-outline-info" type = "submit">Sign Up</button> 
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class = "border-top pt-3">
            <small class = "text-muted">
                Already Have An Account? <a class = "ml-2" href = "#">Sign In</a>
            </small>
        </div> 

    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```